# Can the residue of a singularity be zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

If a complex-valued function $f$ has a singularity at some point $z_0$, it has a Laurent expansion
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_nz^n,
$$
where the coefficient $a_{-1}$ is known as the **residue**. Because each term of the Laurent expansion has a primitive except $a_{-1}z^{-1}$, we can compute the integral along any closed curve containing $z_0$ with
$$
\tag{$\star$}
\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 2\pi ia_{-1}.
$$
My question is, can the residue of a singularity be zero? It doesn't seem so; otherwise, by $(\star)$, the integral along any closed curve in the domain of $f$ would be $0$, which means $f$ at least behaves like a holomorphic function. If this is correct, how might I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be $0$. For instance, since$$\frac1{z^2}=\cdots+0\times\frac1{z^4}+0\times\frac1{z^3}+\frac1{z^2}+\color{red}0\times\frac1z+0+\cdots,$$the residue of $\frac1{z^2}$ at $0$ is $0$.

And, yes, the integral of $\frac1{z^2}$ along a closed path is always $0$. That's not surprising, since $\frac1{z^2}$ has an antiderivative ($-\frac1z$).

Comment: Thanks! I figured something was off with my logic. If I may ask, why doesn't [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) apply here?

Comment: Why do you claim that it doesn't apply here? It does.

Comment: Oh, I guess you can't integrate over a curve that goes through the origin.

Comment: Indeed; when we talk abut $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$, $f$ must be defined at every point of the range of $\gamma$.